# How to stop a jquery draggable function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble stopping a Jquery draggable function, I'm using a button to enable it, and another to stop it although it works on every function I've tried but not draggable.

Here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>stop demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #abc;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  </style>
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"></head>
<body>
 
<button id="go">Go</button>
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>
<div class="block"></div>
   <style>
  #draggable {
   width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
     padding: 0.5em;
     top:5%;
     left: 5%; }
  </style>
<script>
// Start animation
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).draggable();
});
// Stop animation when button is clicked
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).stop();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `$.fn.stop` method stops running animation, but it won't deactivate drag functionality. You should use [`disable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-disable) method of the draggable UI plugin:

```
$( ".block" ).draggable( "disable" );
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/a6CdXcmSvEl1zuEMAy6i?p=info

**UPD.** Thanks to @zfrisch for improved version which also allows enabling disabled draggable: http://plnkr.co/edit/gvMOQwDEgL5aOzjP6ROa

Comment: You're correct, except your code only allows you to disable movement. I think it would be best to show both enable and disable. http://plnkr.co/edit/gvMOQwDEgL5aOzjP6ROa

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
 $(document).on('click', '#go', function(){
  $('.block').draggable( "enable" );
 });

 $(document).on('click', '#stop', function(){
  $('.block').draggable( "disable" );
 });

 //To remove the draggable behavior permanently use:
 //$('#item-id').draggable( "destroy" );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the square's draggable functionality with this script, and I think this might be the shortest way to do this:

```
    // Start animation
    $("#go").click(function() {
        $(".block").draggable({disabled : false});
    });    

    // Stop animation when button is clicked
    $("#stop").click(function() {
        $(".block").draggable({ disabled : true} );
    });
```